# Deploy Microsoft Work Folders on a single machine

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-sharing

As IT unit of a small company, we are investigating the shift from traditional VPN to Work Folders. The roles are set up and the shares created successfully. In fact internally the whole systems works perfect, but it does not allow connections from outside the network. (When I connect remotely through VPN it works as well.)

I've spent 2 days reading lot's of blogs about how people set it up (which they all seem to do differently). But I concluded it must have something to do with the reverse proxy. I've tried installing the 'Web Application Proxy' Role, but that required connection to an AD FS server (that role can't be installed on the same machine and was never needed).

The situation: We have one Microsoft Server 2012R2 machine. Currently we are running AD DS and File server roles on it, along with DCHP and DNS. And we wish to add Work Folders to it.
The question: Can we actually enable Work Folders on the single machine or does it always require two machines? And if possible, what roles would be needed?

**Update:**
After even more reading I've discovered that when I want to use 'Web Application Proxy' it is combination with 'AD FS', and it requires at least two servers. But DirectAccess should be an option as well, and that can run on the same machine. Would that be correct?

Comment: Why do you get an idea a work folder is a replacement for a VPN?

Comment: Traditionally we had our user log-in remotely via VPN in order to access their file shares. But people had trouble settings up the connection. Work Folders seems to be more like Dropbox which people do understand. It could replace our use-case of VPN.

Comment: Ok, for that use case they may be a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just remembered something I've read half a year ago, when I did some reading on work folders as well. The guest account on the AD had to be disabled.

I found connection attempts in the log where user 'Guest' was not found on the AD Server and work folders access was denied. I found this strange and logical at the same time because I was expecting a login pop-up that also showed when I connected through VPN. Since I had not yet entered credentials the server obviously considered me to be a guest. I just didn't think it would be the AD guest account.

So yes you can run work folders along with an AD role (Microsoft best practice analyser disencourages it though). No proxy, no AD FS and no direct Access required.